# "package org.apache.thrift does not exist", upgrading Thrift did not fix anything

Tags: java, dependencies, thrift

I am trying to run a Thrift-generated Java file, I have moved all the Thrift dependencies for Java into folder in my project, but when I try to run it, I'm getting errors saying that various Thrift packages do not exist.

Here are my project directories:

```
Server -> example.java

lib -> libthrift-0.9.2.jar
```

and I am running this command in Terminal:

```
javac -cp lib/ Server/example.java
```

The Thrift version I have is 0.9.2. I've checked the older questions that had this same error, and the general advice seems to be "update Thrift". I upgraded it through homebrew and it did not fix anything. Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: That's on Mac, right? I'd recommend to ask on the mailing list. (PS: 0.9.2 is already the current release)

Comment: https://thrift.apache.org/mailing